# matrix multiplication of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I feel a bit silly asking this, but I can't seem to find the answer

Using arrays in Numpy I want to multiply a 3X1 array by 1X3 array and get a 3X3 array as a results, but because dot function always treats the first element as a column vector and the second as a row vector I can' seem to get it to work, I have to therefore use matrices.

```
A=array([1,2,3])  
print "Amat=",dot(A,A)  
print "A2mat=",dot(A.transpose(),A)  
print "A3mat=",dot(A,A.transpose())  
u2=mat([ux,uy,uz])  
print "u2mat=", u2.transpose()*u2
```

And the outputs:

```
Amat= 14  
A2mat= 14  
A3mat= 14  
u2mat=  
 [[ 0.  0.  0.]  
        [ 0.  0.  0.]  
        [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 8):

[np.outer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)
is a builtin to do that:

```
A = array([1,2,3])
print( "outer:", np.outer( A, A ))
```

(`transpose` doesn't work because `A.T` is exactly the same as A for 1d arrays:

```
print( A.shape, A.T.shape, A[:,np.newaxis].shape )
>>> ( (3,), (3,), (3, 1) )
```

)

Added: `np.add.outer` adds pairs of elements --
`np.outer` is much like `np.multiply.outer`. And
[np.ufunc.outer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) (A, B) combines pairs with any
binary [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html).

Comment: +1, didn't know `np.outer` - but it looks like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> A=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> A[:,np.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> A[np.newaxis,:]
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> np.dot(A[:,np.newaxis],A[np.newaxis,:])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

well one way to obtain this is to work with the `matrix` class/type instead.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([1,2,3])
B = A.T  #transpose of A

>>> B*A 
>>> matrix([[1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]])
```

the objects belonging to the matrix class behave pretty much the same as the arrays. Actually arrays and matrices are mutually interchangeable.